# add a textBox in GridView and the textbox retrieves data from a collection not from  a dataSource

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, collections, sqldatasource

I want to add a textBox  in GridView  knowing that the textbox retrieves data from a collection like ArrayList or List(OF ..) not from a dataSource (ASP.net)

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataSource in code:

```
// in this case the object I am using is:

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsInStock { get; set; }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
   // in the GetProducts() method return the collection
   List<Product> r = GetProducts();
   this.grdSomething.DataSource = r;
   this.grdSomething.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}

protected void grdSomething_EditCommand(object sender, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    this.grdSomething.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

Simply add a bound field column like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="grdSomething" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnEditCommand="grdSomething_EditCommand">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
       <asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

That's it

Comment: but how i can bound it with data from  collection like ArrayList or List(OF ..)

Comment: Oh to bind it you just have to specify the name of the field, gimme a sec I will update the post

Comment: tnksss dudde ...  but unfortunately i found it difficult to understand ..can you be more specific tnksssssssss

Comment: You can return an Array instead, it's equivalent lemme update it. `List<>` implements `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: tnkks agian ^^ but i want to add the data of an collecion .. of course just one attribute .. in a textbox only not the hole gridview